# Can't upload image file from ng-file-upload to web api

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ng-file-upload

I am using this directive ([ng--file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)) to upload image.
I need to include image file to a `POST` to ASP.NET Web API but I don't have any success.
This is my method on server:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SaveData([FromBody]PostModel data)
```

When I post data (from js angular) all data are here except uploaded file:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: path,
            data: data,
            file: photoFile
        }).then(function...
```

I tried to put it in data also but it is always null.
How can I post and get image file on web api?

As a response I am getting:

```
"Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does not have a content type header starting with 'multipart/'.
 Parameter name: content"
```

On this line:

```
var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

var data = {            
            "Username": $scope.username,
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
        };

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('file', $scope.photoFile);

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'path', fd, 
            data: data
        }).the
```

Comment: You can use `Upload.upload()` service to send the file. Read the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData):

html:

```
<div class="button" ngf-select="upload($file)">Upload on file select</div>
```

controller:

```
 $scope.upload = function (file) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);

    //Append other data
    //angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
    //    fd.append(k,v);
    //});

    $http.post('your-upload-url', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .then(function(res){
        // get upload res
    });
};
```

Comment: But how can I get the file on Web API side?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a angular issue....Not good at c#, but you can check [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2)

Comment: I updated question with sending data as you suggest do you maybe have idea why I am getting error from question?

Comment: An obvious error is that, `fd` is just the `data` you thought, like `$http({...,data:fd,..}).

Comment: don't put `transformRequest` and `headers`  in `data`, please refer [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)